# how is geoalchemy2.shape defined and imported?

Tags: python, geoalchemy2

I have geoalchemy2 on my machine. If I import geoalchemy2 and run `geoalchemy2.shape`, I got: `AttributeError: module 'geoalchemy2' has no attribute 'shape'`. But if I run `geoalchemy2.shape.to_shape()`, it can find the method... I am confused on the differences between the two usage of geoalchemy2.shape. Why the differences happen?

Comment: Please provide a [reprex].

Comment: I am going to remove my question since I cannot reliably reproduce my problem either.. I just tried two times. One reproduced the problem, the other didn't.... Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

For me this happened if shapely is not installed in the environment, got it when dockerizing an app.